# Passing values of checkboxes to Perl Script

Tags: javascript, perl, checkbox

I have a simple list of checkboxes, which are NOT in a form. On clicking a button, I want to send the values of all selected checkboxes to a perl script. I do not want to make it a form. Am working with ExtJS and thus don't need any jQuery solutions or hints. Any tips to how I do this?

Illustration :

```
   <input type="button" class="check" value="Send" onclick="foo()"/>

   <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1"/> Checkbox  1
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="2"/> Checkbox  2
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="3"/> Checkbox  3
```

On clicking "Send", I want to write the function foo() so that it can pass the selected values to my perl script hw.pl.

EDIT : I understand that I have to send the parameters using the GET method. But after I wrote the JS function, and have the checked values in a JS array, how do I send that array as a GET parameter?

I wrote the following foo() function, but it doesn't work :

```
function foo(){
     var tclist = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
          if(chk[i].checked) 
            { tclist += chk[i].value + ","; }


    self.location='/cgi-bin/hw.pl?tcs=tclist';



}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to CGI scripting.

Comment: If you don't want a form, you have to send them with the GET method.

Comment: @M42 — Nothing preventing him from using POST.

Comment: Follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). If you want to submit form control values, put them in a form.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo of the parameters, treating the variable name as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
self.location='/cgi-bin/hw.pl?tcs=tclist';
```

to

```
self.location='/cgi-bin/hw.pl?tcs=' + tclist;
```

But please take a look at the other comments. First off, you should be using a form. Second, why use JavaScript at all? If you stuff your checkboxes in a form, their values will be submitted without any client side scripting.